# Spring Boot URL mapping for static HTML

Tags: spring-boot, static-content

My Spring Boot appliation will basically consist of two main "modules":

- A "Web" Module that consists of static HTML pages, available to the public (unauthenticated/anonymouse users); and
- An "App" Module that consists of a number of dynamic pages, each of which require (Spring Security-based) authentication to access

The basic app structure is:

- `index.html`: Homepage, mapped from `http://localhost:8080/`
- `about.html`: About page, mapped from `http://localhost:8080/about`
- `contact.html`: Contact page, mapped from `http://localhost:8080/contact`
- `login.html`: Login page, mapped from `http://localhost:8080/login`
- `dashboard.html`: Dashboard/landing page you get to after logging in, mapped from `http://localhost:8080/account`
- All other pages under `http://localhost:8080/account/*` will be MVC/dynamic pages with typical `@RequestMapping` mappings

What is not clear to me is, for the static ("public web") HTML pages, do I:

- Just use standard controller-based `@RequestMappings` that render some Thymeleaf/Handlebars template (which simply has no data model since the content is static)? Or do I:
- Treat these pages as static content (same as CSS/JS) and serve them as [static content as Spring Boot prescribes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)? If this is the correct option, then how do I achieve the correct URL mappings (so, for example, users can just go to `http://localhost:8080/contact` instead of `http://localhost:8080/contact.html`)?

Comment: what technologie are you using in the authentification ?

Comment: Thanks @KamelMili (+1) - Spring Security, probably with a custom authentication/authorization realm.

Comment: Then spring security can handle your problem with web ignore or ant matcher if you like my solution i could post an answer to show how to deal with spring security configuration class else but anyway you'll be forced to make these pages work with thymeleaf because in these static web pages theres an authentification form who is handled by thymeleaf and spring security so if i understood your problem correctly you need to add them to your mvc resolver and add web ignore to these pages so you could access without authentification

Comment: Thanks again @KamelMili (+1) - yes if you post an answer showing a concrete code example of how to solve this with spring security, this mvc resolver and web ignore, I would graciously accept it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okey first you need to map your views via mvc resolver like this :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/contact").setViewName("contact");

   }
}
```

after mapping your views we need add  the views like `/login` in the `antMatchers` so am assuming you configuration method looks like this :

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http

    .csrf().disable()   

    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/contact","/about", ...).permitAll() //add your static pages here ( public pages ) 
    .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()        
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(successHandler) // i don't think you'll be needing this it's to redirect the user if it's admin or a simple user 
            .and()  // this is for the logout   
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll();   
}
```

after adding your view map in the `antMatchers` spring security wont handle authentification for those pages and that solves your problem

Comment: Thanks so much @Kamel Mili (+1) - one quick question if you don't mind: `registry.addViewController("/login")` returns a `ViewControllerRegistration` instance, whose `setViewName(...)` method expects a string (such as `"login"`, etc.). What type of file is represented by this view name (an HTML file, a Thymeleaf template, etc.) and where do I place this file in my project? In other words: what file defines the `"login"` view? Thanks again!

Comment: it's a simple  html page which begins like this `<html  xlmns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xml:lang="fr">` and am assuming you did add thymeleaf in your `pom.xml` ,and you place your pages under the template folder so thymleaf could map to your views

Comment: Thanks @Kamel Mili (+1), but *where* is the "template folder" located in my project, under `src/main/resources`? Spring needs to know where to find the `login` view...so where (exactly) is it looking? Thanks again!

Comment: It s under src\main\resources\ ps are you sure you added your thymeleaf dependecies in your pom.xml

Comment: The template folder suppose to be in your project and not to be added does your project type is spring starter project